# Proving my contracts are validating the right thing

Tags: c#, validation, unit-testing, code-contracts

I have an interface like so:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(ContractStockDataProvider))]
public interface IStockDataProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collect stock data from cache/ persistence layer/ api
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="symbol"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task<Stock> GetStockAsync(string symbol);

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset the stock history values for the specified date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task UpdateStockValuesAsync(DateTime date);

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the stock prices with the latest values in the StockHistories table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task UpdateStockPricesAsync();

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines the last population date from the StockHistories table, and 
    /// updates the table with everything available after that.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task BringStockHistoryCurrentAsync();

    event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedComplete;
    event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedError;
}
```

I have a corresponding contract class like so:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof (IStockDataProvider))]
public abstract class ContractStockDataProvider : IStockDataProvider
{
    public event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedComplete;
    public event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedError;

    public Task BringStockHistoryCurrentAsync()
    {
        return default(Task);
    }

    public Task<Stock> GetStockAsync(string symbol)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(symbol), "symbol required.");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(symbol.Equals(symbol.ToUpperInvariant(), StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
            "symbol must be in uppercase.");
        return default(Task<Stock>);
    }

    public Task UpdateStockPricesAsync()
    {
        return default(Task);
    }

    public Task UpdateStockValuesAsync(DateTime date)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(date <= DateTime.Today, "date cannot be in the future.");
        return default(Task);
    }
}
```

I made a unit test like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class StockDataProviderTests
{
    private Mock<IStockDataProvider> _stockDataProvider;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _stockDataProvider = new Mock<IStockDataProvider>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public async Task GetStockAsyncSymbolEmptyThrowsArgumentException() 
    {
        //arrange
        var provider = _stockDataProvider.Object;

        //act
        await provider.GetStockAsync(string.Empty);

        //assert
        Assert.Fail("Should have thrown ArgumentException");
    }
}
```

From what I've read, this should be sufficient to pass the unit test, but upon acting, the unit test fails by not throwing an exception.

I'm not trying to test the contract functionality, but I am interested in testing the validation logic to make sure my requirements are met for concrete implementations of the IStockDataProvider interface.

Am I doing this wrong?  How can I verify, using my unit tests, that I have properly specified my inputs?

***UPDATE***

So, while mocking the interface and testing the validation logic does not seem to work, my concrete class (not inheriting from the abstract) validates the inputs properly in testing.  So it may just not be supported in mocking, though I don't quite know why.

Comment: Is code contracts runtime checking enabled in the test project?

Comment: I added an answer as to the "why" it doesn't work for mocks. Let me know if you need any clarifications and I'll update my answer, but I think I demonstrated quite clearly why, and how you can perform testing of your contract conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, I was not able to get a mocked interface to throw the expected exceptions; that being said, I was able to test the exceptions with every implementation of the interface.  It's a bit frustrating, and it seems to fly in the face of the DRY principle, but I was able to unit test these contracts.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your mocks weren't throwing exceptions is quite simple. Interfaces can't have methods. Therefore, you can't specify contracts on an interface directly. But, you already knew this. That's why you created a contract class for your interface (which, by the way, should be a `private abstract class`).

Because you're attempting to mock the interface, the mocking tool knows nothing about the contracts. All mocking tools do is look at the definition of the interface and create a *proxy* object. A *proxy* is a stand-in, a double, and it has no behavior at all! Now, with libraries like Moq, you can make those proxies have behavior by using methods such as `Returns(It.Is.Any())`. But again, this is turning a *proxy* more into a *stub* at this point. Moreover, and more importantly, this wouldn't work with mocking libraries for one reason: the *proxy* is created *on the fly*, at runtime during the test. So no "rewriting" of the *proxy* is being performed by `ccrewrite`.

So how would you test that you specified the right conditions for your contracts?

You should create a new library called *MyProjectName.Tests.Stubs*, for example. Then, you should create an actual *stub* object instance for your interface in this project. It doesn't have to be elaborate. Just enough to allow you to call the methods in a unit test to test that the Contracts work as expected. Oh, and one more important thing for this to work: **Enable** *Perform Runtime Contract Checking* on this newly created stubs project for the Debug build. Otherwise, the *stubs* you create which inherit from your interface will not be instrumented with contracts.

Reference this new *MyProjectName.Tests.Stubs* assembly in your unit test project. Use the stubs to test your interfaces. Here's some code (note, I'm using your code from your post--so if the contracts don't work as expected, don't blame me--fix your code ;) ):

```
// Your Main Library Project
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[ContractClass(typeof(ContractStockDataProvider))]
public interface IStockDataProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collect stock data from cache/ persistence layer/ api
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="symbol"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task<Stock> GetStockAsync(string symbol);

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset the stock history values for the specified date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task UpdateStockValuesAsync(DateTime date);

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the stock prices with the latest values in the StockHistories table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task UpdateStockPricesAsync();

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines the last population date from the StockHistories table, and 
    /// updates the table with everything available after that.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task BringStockHistoryCurrentAsync();

    event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedComplete;
    event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedError;
}

// Contract classes should:
//    1. Be Private Abstract classes
//    2. Have method implementations that always
//       'throw new NotImplementedException()' after the contracts
//
[ContractClassFor(typeof (IStockDataProvider))]
private abstract class ContractStockDataProvider : IStockDataProvider
{
    public event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedComplete;
    public event Action<StockEventArgs> OnFeedError;

    public Task BringStockHistoryCurrentAsync()
    {
        // If this method doesn't mutate state in the class,
        // consider marking it with the [Pure] attribute.

        //return default(Task);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<Stock> GetStockAsync(string symbol)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(symbol),
            "symbol required.");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(
            symbol.Equals(symbol.ToUpperInvariant(), 
                StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
            "symbol must be in uppercase.");

        //return default(Task<Stock>);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task UpdateStockPricesAsync()
    {
        // If this method doesn't mutate state within
        // the class, consider marking it [Pure].

        //return default(Task);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task UpdateStockValuesAsync(DateTime date)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(date <= DateTime.Today, 
            "date cannot be in the future.");

        //return default(Task);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// YOUR NEW STUBS PROJECT
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using YourNamespaceWithInterface;

// To make things simpler, use the same namespace as your interface,
// but put '.Stubs' on the end of it.
namespace YourNamespaceWithInterface.Stubs
{
    // Again, this is a stub--it doesn't have to do anything
    // useful. So, if you're not going to use this stub for
    // checking logic and only use it for contract condition
    // checking, it's OK to return null--as you're not actually
    // depending on the return values of methods (unless you
    // have Contract.Ensures(bool condition) on any methods--
    // in which case, it will matter).
    public class StockDataProviderStub : IStockDataProvider
    {
        public Task BringStockHistoryCurrentAsync()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public Task<Stock> GetStockAsync(string symbol)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(symbol),
                "symbol required.");
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(
                symbol.Equals(symbol.ToUpperInvariant(), 
                    StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                "symbol must be in uppercase.");

            return null;
        }

        public Task UpdateStockPricesAsync()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public Task UpdateStockValuesAsync(DateTime date)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(
                date <= DateTime.Today, 
                "date cannot be in the future.");

            return null;
        }
    }
}

// IN YOUR UNIT TEST PROJECT
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using YourNamespaceWithInteface.Stubs

[TestClass]
public class StockDataProviderTests
{
    private IStockDataProvider _stockDataProvider;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _stockDataProvider = new StockDataProviderStub();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public async Task GetStockAsyncSymbolEmptyThrowsArgumentException() 
    {
        //act
        await provider.GetStockAsync(string.Empty);

        //assert
        Assert.Fail("Should have thrown ArgumentException");
    }
}
```

By creating the project containing stubs implementations of your interface and enabling **Perform Runtime Contract Checking** on the stub project, you can now test the contract conditions in unit tests.

I would also highly recommend that you do some reading on unit testing and the roles of various *test doubles*. At one time, I thought aren't mocks, stubs, fakes all the same thing. Well, yes, and no. The answer is a bit nuanced. And unfortunately, libraries like MoQ, while great!, don't help because they tend to muddy the waters about what it is you're actually using in your tests when using these libraries. Again, that's not to say they're not helpful, useful, or great—but just that you need to understand exactly what it is you're using when you're using these libraries. A recommendation I can make is [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054). There's also a website: http://xunitpatterns.com/.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your example code, your System Under Test (SUT) is the `ContractStockDataProvider` class but you are running your tests against a Mock of `IStockDataProvider`. As things stand the code in your SUT isn't going to be hit.

You should only need to Mock the dependencies of `ContractStockDataProvider` not it's interface.

For the purposes of your answer I simplified your code to this (mainly because I don't have [Code Contracts](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) set up or installed on this machine):

```
public abstract class ContractStockDataProvider
{
    public void GetStockAsync(string symbol)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(symbol))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
 }
```

One thing we need to work past is that `ContractStockDataProvider` is `abstract`. A way around this is to have a dummy implementation in the test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class StockDataProviderTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void GetStockAsyncSymbolEmptyThrowsArgumentException()
    {
        //arrange
        var sut = new StubContractStockDataProvider();

        //act
        sut.GetStockAsync(string.Empty);
    }

    public class StubContractStockDataProvider : ContractStockDataProvider
    {
    }
}
```

We don't need an Assert.Fail because it will fail automatically if the `ExpectedException` is met.

A second way this could be done is to use *Moq* to give an implementation of the abstract class:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void GetStockAsyncSymbolEmptyThrowsArgumentException1()
    {
        //arrange
        var sut = new Mock<ContractStockDataProvider>();

        //act
        sut.Object.GetStockAsync(string.Empty);
    }
```

Personally, I like to keep my stubs and my mocks distinct and feel this muddies the water somewhat and isn't entirely clear as to what is going on. But if you are anti the `class StubContractStockDataProvider : ContractStockDataProvider` snippet in the first example, then this is another way to get the test in.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think you are making some reasonable, yet wrong, assumptions on how .NET code contracts are supposed to work.  I'm not trying to test the abstract, but rather the validation logic on the interface itself, and this is definitely testing the wrong thing.

Comment: I wouldn't be so concerned with testing "the validation logic"--if you mean ensuring Code Contracts is doing the "right thing". You don't test that when you assign 0 to an integer that the .NET Framework _actually_ assigned 0 to an integer? No, that's ridiculous--and you don't own .NET, so there's no need to test frameworks (they should be tested by their authors). Code Contracts is another framework. You don't need to test Code Contracts is working properly. However, you do need to ensure that you specified the right contract, and that contract condition _is_ worth testing.